# Undo in Xcode keeps alternating between ctrl z and cmd z

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

If I want to undo a load of code that I have written the keyboard shortcut keeps alternating between ctrl z and cmd z and I don't know why. Does anyone know why and how to fix it? In the preferences -> Key Bindings the shortcut is the default cmd z for Undo (Edit Menu).

If I click on the edit menu you can see the shortcut on the menu item keeps changing as I undo.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When exactly does the shortcut change to ctrl+z? Never have seen this effect so far.

Comment: It appears to be random. I just typed some code and did a set of undo's and it happened randomly. After the 4th undo then back after the 2nd then 1st undo it was back to ctrl+z etc. Very odd.

Comment: I doubt this is a thing caused by XCode itself. It would have made people crazy and be mentioned in many places. Instead I believe it might be some 3rd party software you might have installed, like keyboard mappers and the like.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I agree I was surprised not see it mentioned places. It's been like it since I bought the mac so I don't think it's 3rd party software although I will check as it could be. Maybe it's how the os is configured. I'll check out the options in the system preferences.